# Windows Phone Hold Gesture

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone application which is relying on the Hold Gesture to begin doing a specific task. The problem is that the default amount of time that has to pass before the Hold Gesture is triggered, is [1 second](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API).

Is there any way that I can change this setting to be 1/2 a second? I understand that I can handle the MouseOver event and add a timer which then fires off my task but I would like to avoid doing this if at all possible.

By the way, I can use either Windows Phone SDK 7.0 or 7.1 for this purpose so there is no limitation there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it isn't possible to change the time of the hold-event.

why don't you use **MouseLeftButtonDown** for it?
would looke like this

```
bool hold = false;
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

private void x_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        hold = true;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);//days,hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
        timer.Start();
    }
private void x_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        hold=false;
    }

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        if(hold = true)
           {
           //et voilà, hold-event after 0,5 seconds
           // place actions that should be handled after 0,5seconds HERE
           }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was hoping to avoid handling any button events. Prior to accepting the answer, I went in to look at the actual gesture code in reflector and it looks like there is no way that I can extend the classes or override any methods because they are reported by classes deep within the framework.